# How to sort 2D array (row-wise) in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#

Need your expert guidance as how to sort a 2D array, row-wise ( means considering each row independently and sort all rows independently of a 2D array) in Visual Studio C#.Example

First row: 5 4 3 6 
Second row: 2 3 1 4

Sorted:
First row :3 4 5 6
Second row: 1 2 3 4

There is a method called Array.Sort (), but it is specific to 1D arrays only.
Thanks and Regards
Asad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 2D array is a jagged array like:

```
int[][] foo = new int[][] { 
    new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 6 }, 
    new int[] { 2, 3, 1, 4 } };
```

you can do it by using LINQ:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
    foo[i] = foo[i].OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is of a 1D array, by 2D array do you mean somthing lke

```
int[2,2] foo;
```

so you'll do some thing like.

```
foo[0,0] = 0;
foo[0,1] = 1;
foo[1,0] = 1;
foo[1,1] = 1;
```

please clarify.

Comment: Actually I have a 2D array of 10x10 elements. Each of the 10 row contains 10 elements. I want to sort each row of this 2D array independent of the other row.

Comment: in that case it would be better for you to have a List of arrays. That way you can loop through them and sort each array. Beter still have a List<> of SortedLists.